# why search working stop in angular js?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, ionic-framework

I am trying to search element in table .But some time it work some time not why ?I will explain my problem I have one table in which i use infinite scroll .There is search input field in top .Using this I am able to search item in table .but I don't know why it is not working

```
<label class="item item-input">
    <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/n2s5u9eifp3y2rz/search_icon.png?dl=0">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model="query">
  </label>
```

plunker 
http://plnkr.co/edit/kRG2OEz0DyQlISaa2iAy?p=preview

when i type **"ubs"** it show "Ubs" rows .but when I type **"ING" or "ing"**  it is not showing any data why ?

secondly Actually I am implementing infinite scroll so only 100 element display .can we search element from 2000 (which I am getting from service )and display data the search result ?

Comment: your plunker works for me (shows data for both 'ubs' and 'ing)

Comment: wait checking .will update you

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/3SHYjdowI6wU1PrAk55Z?p=preview please check .Actually When you first time check "ING" it show data .When you scroll down bottom  and load more data now check again "ING" it not display any any row

Comment: **Update :**

I think there is issue in scrolling
when you run plunker and search anything on search box it display correct result because scrollbar on top position search "ubs" and "ing" get correct result.But when you move you scroller position near to middle and bottom (without loading more data it not showing filter result).it stop filtering why ? Issue regarding scroller position when it is in top it filter perfectly but when it is in between bottom and middle it stop filtering 

http://plnkr.co/edit/3SHYjdowI6wU1PrAk55Z?p=preview